# An example of a submartingale $X=\{X_n\}$ such that $\{X_n^2\}$ is a supermartingale.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

A **submartingale** is a real-valued stochastic process $X=\{X_n\}$ adapted to a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ such that 
$$E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n] \geq X_n.$$ For a **supermartingale** just reverse the inequality.

So I don't want someone to just give me the answer, but I'm having trouble just coming up with a submartingale at all. I've been using Durrett's book and there is a lack of examples for sure. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you so much!

Comment: Since a martingale is a submartingale, you could just use a martingale if you have an example of that.

Comment: The mapping $x\mapsto x^2$ is convex so it takes martingales to submartingales, in general @mheldman

Comment: @Gengar: Indeed, since it is convex and increasing, it takes submartingales to submartingales.  So in your situation, $X_n^2$ will actually be a martingale. A trivial example of this would be $X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X$.  I am not sure if there are any nontrivial examples.

Comment: In fact I'm pretty sure now that such a process must be trivial.  Hint: try to show $E[(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \le 0$.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thank you @NateEldredge!

Comment: @NateEldredge is the trivial example where they're all zero?

Comment: Not necessarily all zero, but at least all the same: $X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = \dots$

Comment: Wouldn't $E[(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2|\mathcal{F_n}]=0$ since $X_{n+1}=X_n$? @NateEldredge

Comment: Yes, **if** we have $X_{n+1} = X_n$ for all $n$ then certainly $X_n^2$ would be a martingale.  What I am claiming is the **converse**: if $X_n$ is a submartingale and $X_n^2$ is a supermartingale then $X_{n+1} = X_n$ a.s. for all $n$.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the confusion @NateEldredge

Comment: Hmm, I just realized my claim is bogus.  A counterexample is the deterministic sequence $X_n = -1/n$.  I think my claim is true if $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale, or if $X_n \ge 0$ a.s. for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Read Theorem 4.2.7 on Durrett's book:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Bz5.png)

It emphasizes the increasing function. On the other hand, $f(x)=x^2$ is decreasing for $x<0$. Therefore we can just set $X_n = -1/n$ then it's submartingale, $X_n^2$ is increasing then it's supermartingale.

You can even play with some randomness on this set to make them real 'variables'.